# How to scrape the extract number of Likes of a tweet via selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape the number 21,633. It is the hover text when I move the mouse to `21.6K Likes`. Please have a look at the below image.

[image]

I successfully move the mouse to `21.6K Likes`

```
href_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"' + '/TwitterDev/status/1621026986784337922/likes' + '")]')
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(href_text)
hov.perform()
```

The hover text `21,633` show up on browser as in the image, however, I could not find it in html source code.
How can I scrape hover text content `21,633` using selenium/beautifulsoup4?

Thanks.

Comment: Nice choice of example tweet.

Comment: thanks! I just want to get away from twitter api. I found the answer myself.

Comment: Weird, I just went on twitter to try out the little hover feature and didn't seem to work for me. I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

No need to hover to get likes etc, data is already available in the html, for example

[image]

So we can access data simply with `get_attribute('aria-label')`

```
from pprint import pprint
tweets = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid=tweetText]')
stats = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role=group]')
for idx,stat in enumerate(stats):
    pprint( dict([['tweet',tweets[idx].text]]+[x.split()[::-1] for x in stat.get_attribute('aria-label').split(',')]) )
```

Output

```
{'Retweets': '88003',
 'likes': '21865',
 'replies': '11390',
 'tweet': 'Starting February 9, we will no longer support free access to the '
          'Twitter API, both v2 and v1.1. A paid basic tier will be available '
          'instead '}
{'Retweets': '695',
 'likes': '2806',
 'replies': '132',
 'tweet': 'Over the years, hundreds of millions of people have sent over a '
          'trillion Tweets, with billions more every week.'}
{'Retweets': '1164',
 'likes': '2649',
 'replies': '470',
 'tweet': 'Twitter data are among the world’s most powerful data sets. We’re '
          'committed to enabling fast & comprehensive access so you can '
          'continue to build with us. \n'
          '\n'
          'We’ll be back with more details on what you can expect next week.'}
{'Retweets': '2819',
 'likes': '1321',
 'replies': '1271',
 'tweet': 'Twitter is enforcing its long-standing API rules. That may result '
          'in some apps not working.'}
{'Retweets': '141',
 'likes': '814',
 'replies': '65',
 'tweet': 'Testing… Testing… Twitter Dev is back online! \n'
          '\n'
          'It’s been a time for change here at Twitter Dev but we have an '
          'important message to share with you. '}
{'Retweets': '151',
 'likes': '245',
 'replies': '48',
 'tweet': 'In this new chapter of Twitter, we will continue to invest in our '
          'Developer Platform, especially our Twitter API. Our goal is as '
          'important as ever: to ensure our entire ecosystem’s success. '}
{'Retweets': '34',
 'likes': '211',
 'replies': '32',
 'tweet': 'Thank you for sticking with us through this transition, and we '
          'cannot wait to keep building together - here’s to what’s next '}
{'Retweets': '175',
 'likes': '500',
 'replies': '59',
 'tweet': 'We’re currently hard at work to make Twitter better for everyone, '
          'including developers! We’ve decided to cancel the #Chirp developer '
          'conference while we build some things that we’re excited to share '
          'with you soon.'}
{'Retweets': '17',
 'likes': '97',
 'replies': '2',
 'tweet': 'We’ll still celebrate the soon-to-be-announced winners of our Chirp '
          'Developer Challenge - stay tuned for more details!'}
{'Retweets': '19',
 'likes': '85',
 'replies': '16',
 'tweet': 'As always, we’re just a Tweet away, so feel free to reach out with '
          'any questions. We’re grateful for your partnership to '
          '#BuildWhatsNext'}
{'Retweets': '26',
 'likes': '111',
 'replies': '12',
 'tweet': ' #TipTuesday:  Ever wondered how to get the video URL from a Tweet '
          'in Twitter API v2?  Here’s a walkthrough, using our TypeScript '
          'SDK. '}
{'Retweets': '34',
 'likes': '297',
 'replies': '248',
 'tweet': 'Fill in the blank \n\nI start my morning off by _____'}
{'Retweets': '633',
 'likes': '4919',
 'replies': '2811',
 'tweet': 'Describe your current project in 3 words! '}
{'Retweets': '80',
 'likes': '197',
 'replies': '16',
 'tweet': 'We just launched Direct Message endpoints to the Twitter API v2.  '
          'You can now create/retrieve Direct Message conversations. And '
          'there’s more— for the first time ever, these endpoints support '
          'group message functionality, only on v2. \n'
          '\n'
          'Read more'}
```